# Does long-time rendering damage CPU?

Tags: 3d

I have a question. **Does long-time rendering (3D animations) damage CPU? Or make it slow or reduce its life?** I am not talking about network systems or big computers used in animation companies. I'm talking about my PC.
When I started rendering my 3D animation with Maya, the fan of my CPU noises and when I opened the Task-Manager window, the CPU usage was in 100 %. So I has been worry and came here to ask.

Comment: Not GD related, voting to close. Think this is a better fit for SuperUser?

Comment: All right, but **I'm still looking for other answers.** And I haven't enough reputation to vote up.

Comment: Welcome to GD!  While this is tangentially related, hardware questions will get better answers on SuperUser.  They have a similar question already (http://superuser.com/questions/314932/can-keeping-my-cpu-speed-at-high-performance-turbo-all-the-time-decrease-its-l), but if that doesn't answer your question you will likely get more detailed answers by posting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

CPUs have provision for overheating — They'll shut down before any damage is done. Unless you're running things really, really hard, it's unlikely you'll have any issues during the normal lifetime of a CPU. You'll likely want a replacement before anything goes wrong.

If you're using a PC, maybe a fan/cooling upgrade would be a good idea, if you think it's struggling.